# Background position different in Chrome than Firefox or IE

Tags: google-chrome, background

I have a background image 1322x622 where I place the content in the middle 660 px.  This is working fine for Firefox 19 (Windows and Ubuntu) and IE 8 but not with Chrome 25.  In Chrome, the background image position appears to be fixed.  The working browsers clip off the background as the browser window is resized smaller and vice-a-versa for resizing larger.

I think the relative CSS is the following:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -661px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
} 

body {
    padding-top: 39px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1322px;
    background: $mkdBrown;
    background-image: url("banana_tree.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-top: 39px;
    min-height: 550px;
    float: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.container {
    width: 660px;
}
```

The website is http://www.monkeykateanddaves.com/ .

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can try positioning the background using the `background-position` property in CSS.

For example:

```
body {
    background-position : 660px 50px;
}
```

You can also make it Chrome specific with the following hack:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    body { 
        background-position : 660px 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes it better than it was, but still not right.  The background still doesn't move when browser is resized.  I can understand where you got 660px from, but where did you get 50px from?

Comment: Those are just arbitrary values I threw in as I'm not sure how the background on the page is supposed to be.

As for the background image appearing to be fixed on Chrome, you could try explicitly specifying `background-attachment : scroll;`. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is very frustrating.  I found a website that works and has the hack, but am unable to reproduce the behavior.  They use percentages, which look very promising.  http://newyork.yankees.mlb.com/index.jsp?c_id=nyy has the hack @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { body.team, body.team #masthead { background-position: 49.99% 0%; } } but this does not work on my site.